# Why we squaring the norm of a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, absolute-value

In Ginzburg Landau equation, there is a term,

$ |A|^2A$

and $A$ is space and time dependent function or $A(x,t)$
Why do we have norm or absolute value under square?  Is square not enough?
My guess is that if we have a complex variable say $ A =-a+ib$ then according to the above we should get $(a^2 + 2ib-b^2)(-a+ib)$.   Without the norm, the results will be different.  Am I correct?

Comment: In Ginzburg Landau equation, $A$ is a complex order field. $|A|^{2}A$ has thrice the magnitude of $A$ but the same phase. Meanwhile, $A^{3}$ has thrice the magnitude and thrice the phase of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're wrong,
suppose
$$ A = -a + bi $$
then
$$ |A| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} $$
$$ |A|^2 = |A||A| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} * \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = a^2 + b^2 $$
and
$$ |A|^2 A = (a^2 + b^2)(-a + bi) = -a(a^2 + b^2) + b(a^2 + b^2)i $$
I think the purpose is to get rid of the square